# How to visualize k-means cluster using R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, k-means

How can I make k-means clustering for my following log2 transformed data set, something like attached image.

My sample df is like :

```
set.seed(5)
cnt_log2 = data.frame(replicate(6, runif(1000,0,20)), 1:10)
names(cnt_log2) = c(paste0("Col",1:6),"geneID")
```

[image: Clustering genes counts image]

Comment: I think that  you are looking for a parallel coordinates plot. You can get that using `parcoord` from the MASS package.

Comment: Look into `ggplot`'s `facet_wrap()` to get similar image with several subplots with same scales on both axes. But to get more concrete help you need to provide more reasonable sample data and the particular clustering. You're asking too many implicit questions here.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using:

```
res_km <- kmeans(df, 5, nstart = 10)
data_plot <- data.table(melt(data.table(class = as.factor(res_km$cluster), df)))
data_plot[, Time := rep(1:ncol(df), each = nrow(df))]
data_plot[, ID := rep(1:nrow(df), ncol(df))]
head(data_plot)
# prepare centroids
centers <- data.table(melt(res_km$centers))
setnames(centers, c("Var1", "Var2"), c("class", "Time"))
centers[, ID := class]
centers[, gr := as.numeric(as.factor(Time))]
head(centers)
head(data_plot)
# plot the results
ggplot(data_plot, aes(variable, value, group = ID)) +
  facet_wrap(~class, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_line(color = "grey10", alpha = 0.65) +

  geom_line(data = centers, aes(gr, value),
            color = "firebrick1", alpha = 0.80, size = 1.2) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Load (normalised)") +
  theme_bw()
```